# I want to move to G20 if g4 contains text, I have the code below but require ideas

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

If Range("h2").Value <> "" Then
    Range("g4").Select
End If
```

Comment: `If Not IsEmpty(Me.Range("G4")) Then Me.Range("G20").Select`?

Comment: I would suggest that it would be rather jarring, from a user point of view, that any change in the worksheet (with H2 being empty) would switch my active cursor to cell G4. First, instead of testing `Range("h2")` with `IsEmpty` (as @BigBen suggested) or with `<> ""`, you should use the changed cell (the `Target`) as some sort of test to even check if H2 has a value or not. If you can explain what you're trying to accomplish, we could perhaps help more.

Comment: I'm pasting in data into H2 and I want to paste to G4 and then G20 without having to move the cursor each time  - hope this explains?

Comment: Why whouldn't you just change the document from your script? You can update any location from your script without opening document and going to each place you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there but missing right condition (G4 & G20) and ***End Sub*.**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
If Range("G4").Value <> "" Then
    Range("G20").Select
End If
End Sub
```

Or you can use @BigBen's solution as well.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
If Not IsEmpty(Me.Range("G4")) Then
    Me.Range("G20").Select
End If
End Sub
```